# Word2Vec embeddings with TF-IDF

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, language-model, tfidf

When you train the word2vec model (using for instance, gensim) you supply a list of words/sentences.  But there does not seem to be a way to specify weights for the words calculated for instance using TF-IDF.

Is the usual practice to multiply the word vector embeddings with the associated TF-IDF weight? Or can word2vec organically take advantage of these somehow?

Answer (score 13):

Word2Vec algorithms (Skip Gram and CBOW) treat each word equally, because their goal to compute *word* embeddings. The distinction becomes important when one needs to work with sentences or *document* embeddings: not all words equally represent the meaning of a particular sentence. And here different weighting strategies are applied, TF-IDF is one of them, and, according to some papers, is pretty successful. From [this question from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47727078/712995):

> In this work, tweets were modeled using three types of text representation. The first one is a bag-of-words model weighted by tf-idf (term frequency - inverse document frequency) (Section 2.1.1). The second represents a sentence by averaging the word embeddings of all words (in the sentence) and the third represents a sentence by averaging the weighted word embeddings of all words, the weight of a word is given by tf-idf (Section 2.1.2).

Answer (score 12):

Train a tfidfvectorizer with your corpus and use the following code:

`tfidf = Tfidfvectorizer ()
dict(zip(tfidf.get_feature_names(), tfidf.idf_)))`

Now you have a dictionary with words as its keys and weights as the corresponding values.

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Yes It Does. Thanks for your help.