# Word2Vec and Tf-idf how to combine them

Tags: nlp, text-mining, feature-engineering, word2vec, tfidf

I'm currently working in text mining ptoject I'd like to know once I'm on vectorisation. With method is better.

- Is it `Word2Vec` or `Tf-Idf` ?
- [Here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/28598/word2vec-embeddings-with-tf-idf) I see we can combine them why that? Does it improve quality of data?
- What about `GloVe`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Word2Vec algorithms (Skip Gram and CBOW) treat each word equally,
  because their goal to compute word embeddings. The distinction
  becomes important when one needs to work with sentences or document
  embeddings; not all words equally represent the meaning of a
  particular sentence. And here different weighting strategies are
  applied, TF-IDF is one of those successful strategies.
- At times, it does improve quality of inference, so combination is
  worth a shot.
- Glove is a Stanford baby, which has often proved to perform better. Can
  read more about [Glove against Word2Vec](https://dsnotes.com/post/glove-enwiki/) here, among many other
  resources available online.

Comment: when combining them I've to perfomr Wrd2vec then tf-idf? I do not know how that should word the output of word2vecis numeric matrix, how tf-idf should handle that??

Comment: Create a matrix of feature first! Can use Sklearn tfidfvectorizer (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html). Here is an example on Kaggle kernel (just googled): https://www.kaggle.com/reiinakano/basic-nlp-bag-of-words-tf-idf-word2vec-lstm